# Plotting mulitple lines on two y axis using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple features which have different ranges on two y axis.   Each axis might contain more than one feature.  Code snippet below includes object "Prin Balances" which is a df which contains datatypes float indexed by dates.   "Delinquent States" is a list containing a subset of the column headers of Prin Balances.

```
Delinquent_States = ['1 Mos','2 Mos','3 Mos','> 3 Mos']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(Prin_Balances['UPB'], '--r', label='UPB')
plt.legend()
ax.tick_params('Bal', colors='r')

# Get second axis
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt.plot(Prin_Balances[Delinquent_States],  label=Delinquent_States)
plt.legend()
ax.tick_params('vals', colors='b')
```

My output needs to be cleaned up, esp the legends.

[image]

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: You can plot it all in one image, but the lines from 0 to 0.05 will of course be too much far from the others. Best way is to plot two subplots.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As simple as:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Generate some random data
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [random.uniform(0,0.05) for i in range(15)], 
                       'b': [random.uniform(0,0.05) for i in range(15)], 
                       'c': [random.uniform(0.8,1) for i in range(15)],
                       'd': [random.uniform(0.8, 1) for i in range(15)],
                       'e': [random.uniform(0.8, 1) for i in range(15)]})
plt.plot(df)
```

Returns:

[image: Plots]

I would suggest however plotting them separately:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(df['a'], 'r', label='Line a')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(df['b'], 'b', label='Line b')
plt.legend()
```

Which yelds:

[image]

ADDED:

You can set different scales for each side of the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df['a'], '--r', label='Line a')
plt.plot(df['b'], '--k', label='Line b')
plt.legend()
ax.tick_params('vals', colors='r')

# Get second axis
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt.plot(df['c'], '--b', label='Line c')
plt.plot(df['d'], '--g', label='Line d')
plt.plot(df['e'], '--c', label='Line e')
plt.legend()
ax.tick_params('vals', colors='b')
```

Not the prettiest, but you get the point.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but how to plot multiple lines with different ranges (per my question) on the same graph with 2 axis?  Your examples are useful but do not answer my question - unless I am missing something?

Comment: There you go. See if this is what you are looking for @GPB

Comment: Almost - how do I plot multiple lines with different colours on each axis?

Comment: Well, isn't that what the code is doing? Each axis refers to a line. The red line is scaled according to the left-most axis, and the blue line is scaled according to the right-most axis.

Comment: I take it your question is rhetorical?  :-).  I've added an update to my question, I cannot figure out how to use a list to label the legend for multiple lines.

Comment: Well it was. Turns out that it was easier than expected. Check edits, hope now it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149504/discussion-between-gpb-and-carlo-mazzaferro).